# Solr join and non-Join queries give different results

Tags: join, solr

I am trying to link two types of documents in my Solr index. The parent is named "house" and the child is named "available". So, I want to return a list of houses that have available documents with some filtering. However, the following query gives me around 18 documents, which is wrong. It should return 0 documents.

```
q=*:*
&fq={!join from=house_id_fk to=house_id}doctype:available AND discount:[1 TO *] AND start_date:[NOW/DAY TO NOW/DAY%2B21DAYS]
&fq={!join from=house_id_fk to=house_id}doctype:available AND sd_year:2014 AND sd_month:11
```

To debug it, I tried first to check whether there is any available documents with the given filter queries. So, I tried the following query:

```
q=*:*
&fq=doctype:available AND discount:[1 TO *] AND start_date:[NOW/DAY TO NOW/DAY%2B21DAYS]
&fq=doctype:available AND sd_year:2014 AND sd_month:11
```

The query gives 0 results, which is correct. So as you can see both queries are the same, the different is using the join query parser. I am a bit confused, why the first query gives results. My understanding is that this should not happen because the second query shows that there is no any available documents that satisfy the given filter queries.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out.

The reason is simply the type of join in Solr. It is an outer join. Since both filter queries are executed separately, a house that has available documents with discount > 1 or (sd_year:2014 AND sd_month:11) will be returned even though my intention was applying bother conditions at the same time.

However, in the second case, both conditions are applied at same time to find available documents, then houses based on the matching available documents are returned. Since there is no any available document that satisfies both conditions, then there is no any matching house which gives zero results.

It really took sometime to figure this out, I hope this will help someone else.